# scala immutable class vals setters

Tags: scala, class, constructor, immutability, setter

Is there exist in Scala some syntaxic sugar to "immutable class setters"?

Here is an example:

```
class Bob (val x:Int, val y:String)
```

In order to change `x` or `y`, I can implement it this way :

```
object Bob {
    def updX (b:Bob) (x:Int) = new Bob (x, b.y)
    def updY (b:Bob) (y:String) = new Bob (b.x, y)
}
class Bob (val x:Int, val y:String) {
    def updX (x:Int) = Bob.updX(this)(x)
    def updY (y:String) = Bob.updY(this)(y)
}
```

This solution is terrible because some of my classes have 8 parameters.

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: You mean like `copy` method on a case class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @insan-e mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37468800/2988), the pattern that is used by case classes, is a `copy` method with parameters matching the constructor and default values matching the `val`s. You can easily implement that yourself:

```
class Bob(val x: Int, val y: String) {
  def copy(x: Int = x, y: String = y) = new Bob(x, y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this also, this syntax is wonderful. Guess I need to go learn more about capabilities of Scala's syntax.

Answer (score 5):

If you make your class a case class, you will get a copy method for free. Case class parameters are automatically immutable, so no need to put val in front of them.

```
case class Bob(x: Int, y: String)

val bob1 = Bob(1, "Bob1")
val bob2 = bob1.copy(y = "Bob2")
```

Comment: Case class with copy seems to be the appropriate solution. Thanks you, I thought they were only useful with deconstruction in pattern matching

Comment: If you don't like the other stuff that comes with a case class, you can always just write the `copy` method yourself.